# Place mail back onto POP server

Tags: macos, imap, pop3, entourage, apple-mail

I have used Entourage to access a POP mailbox where it would delete messages once they had been received, and would now like to use Mail(.app) to read my mail using IMAP. Is it possible to place the messages that Entourage removed from the server back so that Mail can access them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Import Mailboxes](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mail/2.0/en/ml807.html) feature of Mail to copy the messages to mail, where you can copy them back onto the server (which is possible because it uses IMAP).